# Some improper integral

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, moments

While studying problems related to fractional Laplacians $(-\Delta)^s$, I keep come across with type of quantities such as
$$
\int_0^R r^{2k}f(r)\,dr+\int_R^\infty r^{2k}\varphi(r)\,dr-\sum_{j=0}^\infty f_j\frac{R^{2k-2j+2s+1}}{2k-2j+2s+1},
$$
where (we assume every functions are radial) $f(r)=\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty f_jr^{-2j-1+2s}\right)+\varphi(r)$ for $r\geq R$, with $\varphi$ being some smooth function converges to zero at infinite decay rate as $r\rightarrow+\infty$.

If $f$ decays at infinite rate, then $f_j=0$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ so this quantity is just $2k$ th moment of $f$: $\int_\mathbb{R} r^{2k} f(r)\,dr$. However, this is not true without infinite decay assumption on $f$. But as you can easily see, if you take derivative of this quantity with respect to $R$ you get zero and thus the quantity is not dependent on the choice of $R$.

This almost looks like assigning a finite quantity to the improper integral $\int_0^\infty r^{2k}f(r)$, as if $f$ had infinite rate of decay, but of course, that's not rigorous expression in mathematical sense.

I tried to define this quantity rigorously in some notion of improper integral, but I could not come up with the right notion.

Question: Has this quantity been seen by anyone else?

Comment: What is "infinite decay rate"?

Comment: What do you mean by "this" in "define this mathematically"?

Comment: @losifPinelis Let's say Schwarz function for now. Or: for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $C>0$ s.t. $|f|\leq C(1+|x|^2)^{-k/2}$.

Comment: @losifPinelis "this" in "define this mathematically" is the quantity stated above in the first sentence.

Comment: What are the $f_j$'s and $s$?

Comment: Isn't "the quantity stated above" (whatever it may be) is already defined by being "stated"?

Comment: $f_j$ are some expansion coefficients (so in $\mathbb{R}$) and $s$ is some real number in $(0,1]$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I really wish I can answer your questions regarding clarifying my question, but I am not really interested in that direction. Sorry in advance if I do not respond to you from this point.